# Why my object is not cloning correctly in second time?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, clone

I'm having problems with `const allData = [...dataOrdered];` to clone on my function called: reorderData.

My function is for reordering an array correctly and updating the `dataOrdered` the first time.

Extra explain: reorderData is called on Drag and Drop action where "node" is the node that I'm moving and toNode is the node where to put (position = before or after).

Here is my code:

```
//Default vars
const [dataOrdered, setDataOrdered] = useState([]);

//Waiting until we get data to set.
useEffect(() => {
  setDataOrdered(data);
}, [data]);

const reorderData = (node, toNode, position) => {
    //Default values
    const newPosition = position === "before" ? toNode.id - 1 : toNode.id;
    const newNodeWithIDRenew = { ...node.datum, id: "needNewID" };
    const allData = [...dataOrdered];

    console.log("=======[ DEFAULT VARS ]========");
    console.log("DATA BASED:", allData);

    //Addint the newNODE to new position
    const newData = [...allData.slice(0, newPosition), newNodeWithIDRenew, ...allData.slice(newPosition)];

    console.log("=======[ NEW DATA ]========");
    console.log("Data with new item added:", newData);

    //Removing the old value node.
    const dataWithoutNodeMoved = newData.filter((d) => d.id != node.id);

    console.log("=======[ DATA WITHOUT ITEM MOVED ]========");
    console.log("Data without the initial item moved:", dataWithoutNodeMoved);

    //Mapping all new data with item moved to reorder the IDs.
    const finalDataOrdered = dataWithoutNodeMoved.map((d, index) => {
      return { ...d, id: index + 1 };
    });

    console.log("=======[ FINAL DATA ]========");
    console.log("Final DATA:", finalDataOrdered);

    //Saving the new order
    // setDataOrdered(finalDataOrdered);
    setDataOrdered(finalDataOrdered);
};
```

**First USE of my function is OKEY** if I drag and drop item 1 on 2, the new data is [2, 1, 3] and I save it with `setDataOrdered`.

But when I reorder another time, the reordering is working fine but `const allData = [...dataOrdered];` is getting me the value [1,2,3] instead the updated value [2,1,3].

- [Capture 1 (Drag and drop first time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbltw.jpg)
- [Capture 2 (Drag and drop second time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkAqE.jpg)

I don't know why. I'm sure that my code could be improved a lot.

I also read [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/setstate-not-working-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy-lodash-55a015db80ff) that I think that maybe could be my problem.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

There's a mismatch between `node.id` and the rest of `node`'s fields.

It looks like the 2nd time around you're calling the function with `{id: 1, name: "Title Beauty"}`, which doesn't correspond to what's in the list ("Title beauty" has 2 for id).

**Stop reassigning IDs** -- *ID* stands for "identifier", it should normally not change for a given object. If you mean "index", fine, but don't use it to identify your node in the data list if you're also switching them around.

If you for some reason need to keep the node's index (i.e. order, not ID) in a field, make sure it matches the node's actual position in the list.

You can for example do:

```
//Default values
const currentPosition = dataOrdered.findIndex(e => e.id == toNode); // 0-based
const newPosition = position === "before" ? currentPosition : currentPosition + 1; // changed this to account for the position being 0-based
```

Get rid of `newNodeWithIDRenew` and use `node` instead:

```
const newData = [...allData.slice(0, newPosition), node, ...allData.slice(newPosition)];
```

Do this *before* re-adding the node at the desired position, otherwise you'll have 2 items with the same ID, and both will be filtered out:

```
//Removing the old value node.
const dataWithoutNodeMoved = newData.filter((d) => d.id != node.id);
```

Since we're removing an item from the list, it offsets all the indices after the item we removed (which should have been at `currentPosition`), so account for that before using `newPosition`:

```
if (newPosition > currentPosition)
    newPosition--;
```

Finally get rid of this:

```
//Mapping all new data with item moved to reorder the IDs.
const finalDataOrdered = dataWithoutNodeMoved.map((d, index) => {
  return { ...d, id: index + 1 };
});
```

Comment: Hi,

First of all, the component that I use returns me in node (datum) wich contains `{id: 1, name: "Title Beauty"}` inside, so I need to use node.datum and can't use node.id because don't exist.

However in toNode has `{id: 1, name: "Title Beauty"}` inside and not in datum (but this is for the component that I'm using).

Finally, the ID here in my object is just and increment. It could be called the order for example and not ID but in this case, is called ID, but is not de INDEX of my array is just a number to get an order.

Comment: Also, my problem is here the second time `const allData = [...dataOrdered];` that doesn't take the modify object. The rest of the code is okey.

Comment: _"Hi, First of all, the component that I use returns me in node (datum) wich contains {id: 1, name: "Title Beauty"} inside, so I need to use node.datum"_
That's why it could be a good idea to have an **actual** ID too that helps you equate the argument item with an item in your list. Alternatively, just use a field that's supposed to be unique.
I tried to make sense of your second comment did not succeed.